# FACEBOOK/TWITTER login no longer work on Android app after updating Facebook APK (login disappears immediately!)

Tags: android, facebook, twitter-oauth, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I have an App that allows users to log in with their twitter, facebook, and gmail so I can send them updates to each. I just downloaded the newest facebook APK and now I every time I click on the twitter or facebook logins, the login only shows up for a split-second and then disappears. Here's what I've changed:

```
public static Facebook load(Context context) {
    Facebook fb = new Facebook(context.getString(R.string.facebook_App_ID));
    restore(fb, context);
    return fb;
}
```

--It didn't used to take the APP_ID as a parameter but the new APK enforces you to do it here I believe.

```
facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS,new LoginDialogListener());
```

-- This previously took the APP_ID as a parameter but now it is passed in when the facebook object is created.
--NOTE: I already tried using FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH and that did not work.

```
 private final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener 
    {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            System.out.println("fb success");
            FacebookHelper.save(facebook, SMTPSettings.this);
            updateFacebookSumamry();
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            L.p("loginDialogListener",4900374);
            System.out.println("fb error " + error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            L.p("loginDialogListener",4900387);
            System.out.println("fb error " + error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            L.p("loginDialogListener",4900392);
            System.out.println("fb cancel");
        }
    }
```

-I haven't changed anything with my dialogListener. But every time the control moves to the Dialoglistener it just goes straight into the onError function.

Twitter login no longer works but gmail still does. I don't know exactly what i changed that makes twitter no longer work too, but any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I remember having this issue about a year ago on a HTC device, it turned out to be a conflict of sorts between the pre-installed facebook app and the one installed from Market (Google Play). I can't remember exactly how we solved it but you can try uninstalling any pre-installed apps before you download the new APK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that has seen this, I thought I might post what I remember solved the problem. I uninstalled the other facebook apps I had on my phone like Andreas said above. That didn't solve it immediately, but restarting the phone made it work perfectly. I think it had to do with clearing out temporary memory files or something...not a very complicated problem, but all else fails, give it a clean restart!